# How to update ListView on scrolling while retrieving data from server in Android?

Tags: android, http, client-server, android-asynctask

Currently, I'm using AsyncTask to handle Http connection and retrieve data as JSON format.
   Loading all data is trivial but it consumes too much time, so I decided to switch to load 10 items at a time using `LIMIT OFFSET` (mysql).
Next I set up the event `onScroll` for my list view to create a new `AsyncTask` each time user scroll. However, from what I read, `AsyncTask` is stored in a thread pool which is limited 5 threads at a time, so I'm not sure this is a right approach. I'm newbie to client/server app, so could I anyone give me an advice on this issue? Any related article, documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are few useful links for it,

[Android: Implementing progressbar and "loading..." for Endless List like Android Market](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4667064/603744)

[Endless Listview with current Async Task](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6492956/603744)

[Android Endless List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080811/android-endless-list)

http://www.androidguys.com/2009/10/21/tutorial-autogrowing-listview/

http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2010/03/progressively-loading-listviews.html

In simple steps,

> As user scrolls – detect the end of the list 
>  1)Display a progress
>   notification 
>  2)Ask for update 
>  3)Receive update (asynchronously) and
>   extend list

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a `ListView`, I believe I can safely assume that you must be using some sort of `ListAdapter`. Instead of starting a new `AsyncTask` in the `onScroll` event, you should maintain just one single `AsyncTask` to retrieve data from the server, add that data to the `ListAdapter` dataset and then call `notifyDatasetChanged` on the `ListAdapter`.

The `ListAdapter` and `ListView` will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 2):

A typical approach would be e.g. to load 25 initially and then have a footer in the list that displays e.g. the current count and the total count and upon pressing loads another 25 and so on. That would be a paged sort of loading.

When you do that you have to keep the current position and notify the adapter that the list has changed.