# how to populate listview one by one not at once

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I want to populate my custom listview with some lists of data but data is retrieving from my server. In my case listview is populated when all data from server is retrieved which take some time. I want to load my listview in the ways one by one each time the data retrieved. 
In my current logic I use notifyDataSetChanged() for updating the adapter but in this case it refresh all the data at once. Is there any way to load custom list view one by one asynchronously?.

Comment: Just get firrst 10 or whatever number of items from server, after getting data call  for next 10 items and at same time populate list with first available items and so on..!!

Comment: Introduce paging in your listview requests

Comment: @AndiGeeky you might be looking for solution like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921162/how-to-update-listview-on-scrolling-while-retrieving-data-from-server-in-android

Comment: @sasuke : As Dhiraj suggested, Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921162/how-to-update-listview-on-scrolling-while-retrieving-data-from-server-in-android ..!! Thanks Dhiraj.!!